# Sharepoint API PictureThumbnailURL returns unauthenticated

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api

I use the sharepoint search API to get the latest newsarticles from sharepoint.
This works for me 
`https://tentant.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='PromotedState:2'`
I also get returned an `PictureThumbnailURL` property for each item.
When I go to that URL

```
https://tentant.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/shares/u!aHR0cHl0ZXMvT3VyRGVzdGmRWU2Y2ZlZmVmNGUuSlBH/driveItem/thumbnails/0/c400x99999/content?preferNoRedirect=true
```

I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"code":"unauthenticated","message":"Unauthenticated"}}
```

Why does this occur and why does this happen for only a few images?
It does not occur for all images, only for some of them, others are working.
How does the browser know if you are authenticated or not?

Is there a way to get the images returned as binary (base64) ?

Comment: are you showing news in SharePoint Site itself or in other application?

Comment: I get the news from sharepoint to show in another application

Comment: what is the type of application? is it web application? which technologies/language you have used there? which type of authentication you have used for search query?

Comment: I used Oauth2 for authentication, its a webapplication. I used PHP. But thats not important here. My application works succesfully, only in some cases the image from the PictureThumbnailURL that is returned can't be fetched

Comment: I tried and I am receiving link in PictureThumbnailURL which is working without authentication as well. I am receiving in format like https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/afdcache/ some id

Comment: Okay, my format is different as listed above. That url does not work without authentication

Comment: If you are receiving different link then you have to download get binary of the image using same authentication type which you are using for search query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188528/display-image-in-sharepoint-that-requires-basic-authentication for more details

Comment: Check specially answer in the link which I have given in previous comment

Comment: And where do I get the imageID from?

Comment: you can use whole value of PictureThumbnailURL to get binary as host url. according to above link it should be $host.  Also don't forget to set authentication headers for OAuth2

And yes I am not Php Guy so this is just my suggestion not sure whether it would work or not.. you could try it

Comment: Alright thank you, ill try

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela I still dont understand what U meant by `https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/afdcache/ some id` where do I get this id? Im still struggling with this